# Trouble Connecting to SQL Server using PHP from localhost

Tags: php, sql-server, connection, localhost

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to connect to a remote SQL Server from my local test environment. I can connect to the server using Toad for SQL Server, but I'm not sure why it's not working through PHP. Here's what I have:

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "db",
                        "UID" => $user,
                        "PWD" => $pwd);
$connection = sqlsrv_connect("ip address", $connectionInfo);
if(!$connection) //error message
```

I've tried every possible combination I could think of - using the server/instance name, explicitly giving the port (1433), using Windows authentication by removing UID and PWD - all of which work fine with Toad. I don't know what else I can try, or what I'm missing.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have SQLSRV extension enabled and appropriate SQL Server client installed on the server you are trying to connect from? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: @MikeBrant I have SQLSRV enabled - the only error message I was getting was the one I was printing out. Though, I think I found the problem - I'm missing the SQL Server Native Client ODBC Driver. I'll report back if that fixes the issue. Thanks!